# Convert files of .ddf Format to other formats in c#

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, ddf

I've got some .ddf format files from a webservice.

I found multiple softwares to open and read the files manually , but Is there any way *I can Convert files of .ddf Format to some other formats* like "**.csv**" or "**.xls**" ( using c#? )

Can anyone give some advices? Thanks.